# What is the difference between IHttpControllerSelector and IHttpControllerActivator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

What is the difference between IHttpControllerSelector  and IHttpControllerActivator ?

Answer (score 5):

The `IHttpControllerSelector` is used to match a single `HttpRequestMessage` to the controller that should handle that message.  It returns an `IHttpControllerDescriptor` which basically describes the controller `Type` that needs to be activated.

The `IHttpControllerActivator` runs *after* the `HttpControllerSelector` and uses the descriptor to activate the described controller (i.e. instantiate the controller `Type`).

Both of these are normally customized and replaced for specific dependency injection frameworks since each DI framework tends to work a little bit differently.  However, I've replaced replaced the `IHttpControllerActivator` to do more advanced things as well.